# Changing Font Style and Color for Column Header in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I searched that for changing Header color for a ListView we use:

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Pink, e.Bounds);
    e.DrawText();
}
```

And we use the same event for changing Header Style for ListView:

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
    {
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        e.DrawBackground();

        using (Font headerFont =
            new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9, FontStyle.Bold)) //Font size!!!!
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Header.Text, headerFont, 
                Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, sf);
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is I want to change both Header color as well as Header style. So I wrote like this:

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Pink, e.Bounds);
    e.DrawText();

    using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
    {
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        e.DrawBackground();

        using (Font headerFont =
            new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9, FontStyle.Bold)) //Font size!!!!
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Header.Text, headerFont,
                Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, sf);
        }
    }
}
```

But if I execute this code, the Header is changing to Bold, but Header color is not changing. To change them both (i.e., Header color and Header Style) what am I missing? I do not understand.

Comment: `e.DrawBackground();` looks wrong - if you are filling the rect with your own color, why ask LV to do it also?

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah but when i remove it Header is showing twice. What i have to do now?

Comment: get rid of `e.DrawText()` as well.  `TextRenderer.DrawText` would be more appropriate for rendering control text (vs `DrawString`)

Comment: @Gopi: See answer below. When you remove it you are seeing duplicate drawing since you draw the text via the ListView and by yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, i.e. skip the call to `e.DrawText()` and `e.DrawBackground()`:

```
private void list_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
{
    using (var sf = new StringFormat())
    {
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

        using (var headerFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9, FontStyle.Bold))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Pink, e.Bounds);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Header.Text, headerFont, 
                Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, sf);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. When I removed e.DrawText() it shows as I wanted.

Comment: Be carefull to only `FillRectangle()` before `DrawString()`

Comment: this code works if I set the attribute "owner draw" to true. But now my data/rows wouldn't be shown anymore, some idea?