# WinForms Column Header FontStyle

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am currently trying to make a Dialog with a ListView that takes its Items from a MySQL Database. I just got it working and now I want to get the Header to have bold Text.

This is my current Code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        lvInstrumente.Columns.Add("ID", 30, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvInstrumente.Columns.Add("Hersteller", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvInstrumente.Columns.Add("Instrument", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvInstrumente.Columns.Add("Preis", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvInstrumente.Columns.Add("Typ", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvInstrumente.Columns.Add("Farbe", 110, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvInstrumente.Columns.Add("Beschreibung", 550, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        lvInstrumente.FullRowSelect = true;
        lvInstrumente.GridLines = true;
        lvInstrumente.View = View.Details;
    }

    private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        // Verbindung zu DB aufbauen
        var db = new MySqlDB("localhost", "3306", "musicstoreuster");
        var h = db.Connect();
        if (h == null)
            return;// Wenn die Verbindung nicht klappt, steigen wir hier aus

        var list = db.Select("product");


        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());

            var ds = item.Split(new char[] { ';' });
            ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(ds);
            lvInstrumente.Items.Add(lvItem);   
        }

        db.Close();
    }
```

To make the Header Bold I ended up with this "solution"

```
for (int i = 0; i < lvInstrumente.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            lvInstrumente.Columns[i].ListView.Font = new Font(lvInstrumente.Columns[i].ListView.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
```

But now when I press the Select Button everything is Bold.
What do i need to add/change to Prevent the Items from also being Bold?

Comment: If you are set on using ListView, then you'll have to set OwnerDraw to true for your ListView and implement DrawColumnHeader on your own, as is done here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27766256/891715 or here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9040411/891715

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the Font before you add the item. Some thing like this:

```
var ds = item.Split(new char[] { ';' });
ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(ds);

//set the font to the item
lvItem.Font = new Font(lvItem.Font,FontStyle.Regular);

Items.Add(lvItem);
```

this works, i tested :v
[image]

Also i've been testing and to make the headers bold, with only this line works fine

```
lvInstrumente.Columns[0].ListView.Font = new Font(lvInstrumente.Columns[0].ListView.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```