# Making only headers bold in a ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

In WinForms, how to make only the header text bold? At the moment, I have the following code:

```
myListView.Columns[0].ListView.Font = new Font(myListView.Columns[0].ListView.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

This makes the headers bold, but each of the *items* are also bold, which is not the desired result.

Comment: myListView.Columns[0].ListView points to the same listview. So you are setting the font of listview only not column font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was asked already before you can check on this [WinForms Column Header FontStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370083/8795884)

Set the ListView font to Bold before adding an item.

```
listView1.Font = new Font(listView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Every time adding an item set its font.

```
listViewItem.Font = new Font(listViewItem.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

I hope it helps you. Happy coding.